# Which datasource method can be overridden when inserting new record into table?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

In a form, when creating new record, it will insert into table, which method can be overridden (insert method is not available) in datasource to handle some functionalities during inserting in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009 with X++?

Comment: The answer to this may depend on what functionality that you want. There are several methods that you could override, including write and validate write.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The write method on a datasource is for inserts/updates and the create method is for create.

See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa893931(v=ax.10).aspx

Mentioned above, "validateWrite" would be used specifically for validating the write.  If you want to perform functionality from the form data source, the best place would be the write method.